# How to update by passing array values from HTML to Rails controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, haml

I am trying to update a record from an html.haml form.

HTML.HAML:

```
%input{:name => "post[my_card_ids][]", :type => "hidden",value: "#{post["my_card_ids"]}",id: "my_card_ids"}
```

When I inspect the HTML page, the values are exactly like they should be.

HTML inspection:

```
<input id="my_card_ids" name="post[my_card_ids][]" type="hidden" value="[5d1b83a6616b6523a9020000, 5d1b9893616b653abd0b0000]">
```

But when I receive the same params in the controller, they become like this:

Rails Console:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"my_card_ids"=>["[\"5d1b83a6616b6523a9020000\", \"5d1b9893616b653abd0b0000\"]"]
```

The record is being saved with all the extra paranthesis and quotation marks, because it is being passed as a string I'm guessing.

How do I pass the array cleanly, as shown in the HTML inspection and update the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create an array in the parameters you want to create a hidden input for each value in the array:

```
- post["my_card_ids"].each do |card_id|
  %input{ name: "post[my_card_ids][]", type: "hidden", value: card_id, id: "my_card_ids_#{card_id}" }
```

This works since Rack merges parameters with names ending with `[]` into an array. Its also how the built in [FormOptionsHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.6/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) works.

Comment: I also want to add an if condition to enter the loop if post["my_card_ids"].present? 
What would the indentation look like to achieve that?

Comment: Add the condition `- if post["my_card_ids"].present?` and then indent the code that should be covered by the condition by two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You put array as string to hidden field.

Try:

```
%input{:name => "post[my_card_ids]", :type => "hidden",value: "#{post["my_card_ids"].join(','}",id: "my_card_ids"}
```

And in the controller

```
params[:my_card_ids].split(',')
```

Comment: It is being passed as a string already, applying join method gives an error "undefined method join for string"

Comment: I also have the split method already applied in the controller. The issue I'm trying to resolve is, how to ensure that an array is passed instead of a string

Comment: This won't work since the value of the parameters is an array with a string containing an "escaped" ruby array. `["[\"5d1b83a6616b6523a9020000\", \"5d1b9893616b653abd0b0000\"]"]`. Which is what you get when you call `#to_s` on an array. While you could use YAML or JSON to parse it into an array again there is a better solution altogether.